# Section cut through (solid) geometry

Tags: opengl, screen, intersection, csg

I'm looking for image based (screen space) technique to render section cuts through arbitrary (solid) geometry. I found and studied image based CSG ([Kirsch 05 / OpenCSG](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix05/tech/freenix/full_papers/kirsch/kirsch.pdf)) but I found it to be perhaps a bit of a overkill for my case, where all I need is a section plane cut.

[image]

Above is a naive implementation using a `discard` in the fragment shader, but that obviously is not even half-way there as I need to close the gaps. Does anyone know of a technique/hack I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by gaps you mean you want to render caps to the top. Not sure if this is still the preferred approach, but you can use clipping planes with stencils. An example would be [here](http://glbook.gamedev.net/GLBOOK/glbook.gamedev.net/moglgp/advclip.html).

An alternative approach might be to render your object with just backfaces first. The problem is that your geometry has diagonal front faces on the corners which would probably cause artifacts since they'd render over the back face cap color. That said if you can remove those artifact front faces from your geometry it should work. The only big problem you might see with this approach is anti-aliasing artifacts on the edges depending on your AA technique.

Answer (score 2):

To close gaps created from a plane cut, assuming otherwise closed geometry, you should be able to do it with just the depth buffer.

- Depth buffer contains front face depth after rendering the cut geometry.
- Render backfaces (using an inverted cull mode), thus selecting only the pixels that would appear on the gaps.
- Use plane normal instead of interpolated vertex normal for lighting.
- To generate planar texture coords and/or pixel position, in the shader:

  - Get view space position, intersect ray from (0,0,0) to this position with view-space plane to get the pixel view-space position.
  - Transform that position back to world space (by multiplying it with an inverse view matrix).
  - Generate coords from dot products between world space position and plane tangents (they can be arbitrarily selected, as long as they're 90 degrees apart from each other and plane normal).

As for those internal triangles, if they're overlapping (both front- and backfaces), some depth bias will be enough to remove them. Otherwise, I'd suggest removing them some other way.

Comment: Sorry I can't decide which answer is better. Both outline the same solution. Yours has +1 for giving a hint on calculating texcoords. But the link @Sirisian 's answer is super helpful too.